# ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD on saving some strings to mysql

Tags: mysql, regex, node.js, utf-8

I'm using node.js, `node-mysql` npm module, have a utf8 column in mysql (`sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES`), and can store "regular" utf8 chars normally, but for some input it throws this:

`AssertionError: Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xF3\xA5\xB5\xA5\xEF\xBF...'`

I imagine this is due to some characters being outside `utf8`. I know it's possible to use `utf8mb` charset in mysql, but in this case I don't care about those characters and want to just remove them from a string instead of changing mysql config.

Is it possible to remove such characters using node.js?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[RFC here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629) features a list of unicode char codes along with the number of chars they take:

```
   Char. number range  |        UTF-8 octet sequence
      (hexadecimal)    |              (binary)
   --------------------+---------------------------------------------
   0000 0000-0000 007F | 0xxxxxxx
   0000 0080-0000 07FF | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0000 0800-0000 FFFF | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
   0001 0000-0010 FFFF | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx
```

While the error message I've provided did not show any wide characters:

```
node -e 'console.log("\xF3\xA5\xB5\xA5\xEF\xBF")'
ó¥µ¥ï¿
```

And [this](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) page shows that all of those characters are 2 byte ones, I've still tried removing wide (3 or more octets) characters from my string with `.replace(/[\u0800-\uFFFF]/g, '')`, and it worked!

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  The replace was very handy!

Comment: .replace(/[\u0800-\uFFFF]/g, '') - SOOO AWESOME!! that solved all my JSON problems being stored into LONGTEXT columns, thank you soooo much!!!

Comment: This is stripping characters, though, right? Like I will have missing characters that are meant to be in the text.

Comment: This solution is omitting all apostrophes and hyphens  in my string. Any better solution?

Answer (score 7):

Convert the column to the **utf8mb4** character set.**utf8** character set is limited to characters

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Comment: @Fluffy maybe he doesn't. But his solution is worked out pretty well for me.

Comment: Hmm, I still get the error with `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci` on the table.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is not exactly the answer you were looking for but many will actually be interested in fixing it in the right way, so:

**1. Backup your database:**

```
mysqldump -h HOSTNAME -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > PATH_TO_FILE
```

Example:

```
mysqldump -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p music > ~/music-db-backup.sql
```

This will ask you for your db password. If you want to include the password in the command - add it right after the `-p` without space between, e.g. `-pJazzMusic`.

**2. Change your fields character set** `utf8mb4` and collation to `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` (Unicode v9 compatible). Also it is a good idea to update the tables and DB itself as well.

Update Database:

```
ALTER DATABASE <database-name>
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Update Table:

Update a table and its fields in one go: 
(Keep in mind that on larger tables it might take significant amount of time and produces significant IO spike)

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table-name> CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Or, alternatively, update table and fields on case-by-case basis:

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table-name>
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

This way pre-existing fields will maintain their old charset/collation.

Converting individual field:

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table-name>
MODIFY COLUMN <column-name> varchar(64)
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
NOT NULL;
```

**3. Make your connection to use `utf8mb4`**

You can either sent this query to your DB right after connection:

```
SET NAMES "utf8mb4"
```

[MySQL Documentation - Set Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-names.html)

Or check with your DB framework documentation on how to do it in simpler way. 
For example TypeOrm has `charset` connection property:

```js
import { createConnection } from 'typeorm';

const connection = await createConnection({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3306,
    charset: 'utf8mb4'
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using TYPEORM then you can change the charset on both Entity level and Column level**.

*For entity level*

```
@Entity({engine: 'InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci'})
```

*For Column Level*

```
   @Column({charset: 'utf8mb4',collation: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'})
```